# Why does TI-84 show scientific notation for zeros sometimes but not others?

Tags: floating-point, calculator

When graphing a function and then going through the process to calculate the zeroes (left bound, right bound, guess), is there a reason that sometimes it shows y = 0, but there are other times when it will show a very small number in scientific notation, for example y = 1.8 E -12? I assume it is due to the fact that the calculator is simply approximating and it can only go down to a certain number of pixels to do so, but then again, when you're literally calculating "zeroes" why would it not just automatically know y should equal zero?

Comment: Computers and machines have to deal with machine precision.  How each handles it is different.  Did you know for instance that $0.1+0.2$ is not equal to $0.3$ according to many languages but is instead equal to [0.30000000000000004](https://0.30000000000000004.com/)?  I would imagine something similar is happening here.

Comment: It would help us if you could give a couple of specific examples

Comment: Calculators have limits in the order of magnitude they can handle. Thus $y=0$ may mean two things, i) $y$ is in fact Null, or ii) the result was below the limit it can handle. In contrast, if it shows something like 1.8E-12 where you expected Zero as result, the "slipup" of the operations summed up to a value *within* the displayable magnitude.

Comment: On top of the machine precision issues already mentioned, when the calculator finds zeros of a function, it is using a search algorithm that starts with an initial guess to the 0, finds the value of the function at the guess and uses it refine the guess. It does this repeatedly. Usually, none of guesses is completely accurate, so the refinement process has no end. In order to get a value out, at some point it has to say "this is close enough". When you see the $y$ value is not $0$, that is because it is the $y$ value of the approximate root it found, not the exact root..